# Spring XD: Problems running Batch Job. "Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler"

Tags: spring, cron, spring-batch, jobs, spring-xd

I'm trying to run my first job in spring XD. I deployed the job, and I created a stream which includes a cron, which will trigger my Job. This is what I have so far:

this is my xml config:

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />

<batch:job id="myJob">
    <batch:step id="fileReaderStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="fileReader" writer="flatFileWriter" commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="fileReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:/test-files/inbound.csv" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="xxx,yyy,zzz" />
                    <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.whatever.mapper />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="flatFileWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:/test-files/outbound.csv" />
    <property name="appendAllowed" value="true" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And this is what I've got in the logs:

```
    2017-02-08T19:05:05-0300 1.3.0.RELEASE ERROR DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Exception deploying module
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0': Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler#0' of type [org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler] while setting bean property 'targetObject'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/job/job-module-beans.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213) ~[spring-xd-module-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217) ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200) ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployJobModule(DeploymentListener.java:291) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) [guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/job/job-module-beans.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
2017-02-08T19:05:05-0300 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ZKJobDeploymentHandler - Deployment status for job 'testmyJobJunit1': DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0': Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler#0' of type [org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler] while setting bean property 'targetObject'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/job/job-module-beans.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployJobModule(DeploymentListener.java:291)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/job/job-module-beans.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 37 more
}
2017-02-08T19:05:05-0300 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Path cache event: path=/deployments/modules/allocated/c954bb24-fc61-4cfd-b8b2-7a76cc85af1a/testmyJobJunit1.job.myJobJunit1.1, type=CHILD_REMOVED
2017-02-08T19:05:05-0300 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Undeploying module [ModuleDescriptor@2fc21706 moduleName = 'myJobJunit1', moduleLabel = 'myJobJunit1', group = 'testmyJobJunit1', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type = job, parameters = map[[empty]], children = list[[empty]]]
```

Comment: Please provide us with more information such as your job-module-beans.xml and some configuration code. Judging from the log It seems like you are providing the wrong type of object to the targetObject of the JobLaunchingMessageHandler. You are providing it a SimpleJobLauncher, but it needs to be of type JobLauncher.

Comment: I've updated the description. I've added the whole code that I'm using in my xml file. @Sander_M Like you said, the issue is it is expecting a JobLauncher instead of a simpleJobLauncher (see this code http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.xd/spring-xd-dirt/1.0.3.RELEASE/META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/job/job-module-beans.xml)

But at the same time SimpleJobLauncher IS a a JobLauncher, since SimpleJobLauncher implements JobLauncher.

Also I can set directly a JobLauncher, because somehow I have to set my JobRepository.